# basis theorem in holomorphic tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry

I know that if $(x^1, \cdots, x^n)$ is a local coordinate system in a manifold $M$ then $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1},\cdots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\}$ forms a basis for the tangent space $T_pM$ and any $v \in T_pM$ can be expressed as $v = \sum v(x^i) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$. I want to know that can we say the same for holomorphic tangent space which is  spanned by $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial z^1},\cdots, \frac{\partial}{\partial z^n}\}$?i.e.,Is it true  that any element $X$ of the holomorphic tangent space can be expressed as $X = \sum X(z^i) \frac{\partial}{\partial z^i}$ ?

Comment: Well, what is your definition on holomorphic tangent space?